# How to implement a loader using a program?

Tags: c, assembly, operating-system, kernel

I know that a loader loads a program into memory. But how can I implement it using a program? Using assembly or C. This might be very useful. Or atleat a reference.

Comment: Atleast a reference.

Comment: Surely you are capable of Google searching also?  Please read how to ask a question before posting on StackOverflow again.

Comment: Everyone is capable of google searching for anything, then why stackoverflow?

Comment: For questions that **don't have an answer**.  I'm not here to argue the existence of StackOverflow with someone who is too lazy and foolish to Google search something before asking.

Comment: Did you do ANY research of your own?  Any loader is going to be OS-specific and decidedly non-trivial.  You need a book, not an SO answer:(

Comment: I have googled it and I cant find the answer so only I came to stackoverflow. But still its ok I will try. Thank you and sorry sir Mr.Luke Park

Comment: Why not examine an open-source loader, eg. linux?

Comment: Note that Googling 'Process loader' gives: 'About 27,300,000 results'.  You say that none of them are of any use to you?

Comment: Apologies for seeming harsh, it's just good to provide as much information as you can when asking questions.  Good luck to you.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you already understand this, not sure.  A program loader at a high level simply reads/downloads/accepts the program, parses the file format if required.  Places the program in memory, and jumps/branches to it.

Now if you get more specific, say a bootloader for a processor you generally dont have a file system yet or such things so maybe you can only accept programs that are already on the flash, one of your main use cases, or allow developers to download test versions, destined to be the program on the flash, xmodem, ymodem, or other protocols.  Maybe if there is ethernet then that way or usb if available and makes sense or removable media (sd cards, etc).  At the end of the day you still support some type of format be it just the raw memory image of the program or some other formats (intel hex, motorola srecord, maybe elf, etc).

An operating system has a lot more work to do, because take windows or linux or mac right now, write a simple application that reads and parses a simple program, read that program into your applications memory space or malloc some, whatever, then try to branch to it.  The operating system stops you, there are ways around this, but that is not the point, you are an application you are not the operating system.  But if you were the operating system loader, then you simply have more permissions, being the operating system you have designed what your file format is, what the agreed entry point address is, what the system interface is for applications making calls, etc.  Programs have to conform to your rules, you would then read the binary, parse it (perhaps you only support .elf file formats for example), allocate memory for the program per your rules and the programs desired allocation of resources (ideally, initially, part of the file format), per your operating systems rules you setup the virtual address space and point it where the program has been loaded, and then branch to the program changing from super user to user mode on the way.

Your question is extremely vague though, cant understand if you understand the basics and want detail (an application is not a loader on an os with protection, so simply go read the source for linux or bsd, etc), or dont understand the basics (make a little bootloader for a microcontroller or use an instruction set simulator if you dont want to buy a microcontroller).

Answer (score 1):

I feel as if the best manner of doing what I think you are trying to do is fork a process off, and create a process running within it? This is, if it's what you're asking best done with the unistd.h library, in both C and C++, and if you want to get a bit more direct the PThreads library. However if you don't at the moment know how these things are called, I recommend heavy reading before you mistakenly create a fork bomb, and crash your system.Look into the openpub documentation if needed. However I heavily recommend cleaning up this question, and I also feel that it's been asked a bit often on this site as well.